# Starting vim with a command typed in, but not executed (i.e. waiting for argument)?

Tags: command-line

I know I can start vim with a command by executing `vim +"MyCommand"`, but if `MyCommand` takes a parameter it would be nice to start vim, as if I already typed `:MyCommand` but not actually executing it, so I can pass the argument with vim open, rather than from the command line (use case would be a trivial alias in bash). I tried `vim +"normal :MyCommand"` but that doesn't work it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `feedkeys()`:

```
vim +'call feedkeys(":MyCommand")'
```

Comment: @Quasímodo How is that possible? It feels like you would need to have `:` somehow overridden in the vimrc for this NOT to work? Also as a ps.: making an alias with this is not trivial because of the amount of quotes, so ended up making a function.

Comment: There is an argument to feedkeys to prevent mappings from expanding. Re: the shell, yes, a function of script should be much easier to work with.